# How to Sum a value with row duplicates in the Django orm query

Tags: django, django-orm

### Goal

I am looking for a way to get a sum of values

---

### Models

```
class ModelX(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)


class ModelA(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
    modelxs = models.ManyToManyField(ModelX, through='ModelC')

class ModelC(models.Model):
    modelb = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)
    modelx = models.ForeignKey(ModelX)
    modelxx = models.ForeignKey(ModelX, related_name='modelcs')
```

### What I've tried

```
Modelx.objects.values('name').annotate(
    total=Sum('modelcs__modelb__modela__value')
).values('total')
```

And

```
sum_qs = (
    ModelA
    .objects
    .filter(modelb_set__modelc_set__modelxx=OuterRef('id'))
    .values('modelb_set__modelc_set__modelxx_id')
    .order_by()
    .distinct()
    .values('value')
)

qs = ModelX.objects.annotate(
    total=Subquery(sum_qs.values('value')))
```

### The Problem

1. ModelC can contain multiple rows with the same **modelxx** relation.  This will cause duplicates, and cause the sum of 'value' to get duplicated

### Example

Below are the example models where I would expect to see the 10 as stated in the expected results up top: **edit**

```
foo = ModelX.objects.create(name='Foo')
bar = ModelX.objects.create(name='Bar')
baz = ModelX.objects.create(name='Baz')

modela1 = ModelA.objects.create(value=10)
modela2 = ModelA.objects.create(value=10)

modelb1 = ModelB.objects.create(modela=modela1)
modelb2 = ModelB.objects.create(modela=modela2)

modelc1 = ModelC.objects.create(modelb=modelb1, modelx=foo, modelxx=bar)
modelc2 = ModelC.objects.create(modelb=modelb1, modelx=bar, modelxx=bar) # This would be a cause a duplicate as a relation to ModelX through modelxx
modelc3 = ModelC.objects.create(modelb=modelb1, modelx=baz, modelxx=baz)
modelc4 = ModelC.objects.create(modelb=modelb2, modelx=bar, modelxx=bar)
```

### Expected Results

**EDIT** {'Bar': 20, 'Baz': 10}

This can also be as a QuerySet of ModelX to serialize

---

Comment: It's unclear by what fields you want to group the summed values. If you want to group them by ModelX, you cannot avoid duplicates as more than one ModelX can relate to a ModelA, and how should the database decide for which of the several related ModelX to count a ModelA that is referenced multiple times?

Comment: I thought there may be a way to get the distinct values of ModelA (id, value) where there exists a ModelX.  Then sum up those distinct values.

Comment: OK, so the goal is to sum up all ModelA that have a relation to a ModelX in a single value, without grouping by ModelX?

Comment: I'd like it to be grouped by ModelX as well.  Let me edit my above post for clarification

Comment: That's possible, but you'd need nested queries to first select unique A-X combinations (inner query) and then sum up A.value grouped by X (outer query). This is unfortunately are not supported by the Django ORM; you could use a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Comment: Any help would be appreciated... I suspected as much it was possible